# how do you pass an array index to a jquery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would you use an array index as a jquery selector?

for example if I have:

```
 array[0] = someId;
 array[1] = someId;

 for(var i; i<array.length; i++){
     $("#"+array[i]").find(.....)
 }
```

I would like to be able to use the value stored in the array index as my id for the selector.

thanks

Comment: jquery selectors are just strings.

Comment: `$("#"+array[i])`.  Remove the extra `"` after `[i]`.

Comment: what does not work with your code (except the one quotation mark to much)?

Comment: $("#"+array[i]).find("#someELement"); - You had a stray closing " in your string, no need for it.

Comment: Closing *and* down-voting because this is a syntax error. Learn your tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine, except for the extra `"`.
jQuery selectors are ordinary strings.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the last quote in selector  `array[i]` will be a string and all you are doing is concatenating a string to create the selector

```
$("#"+array[i] ).find(.....)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to set `i` to `0`:

```
 array[0] = someId;
 array[1] = someId;

 for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
     $("#"+array[i]).find(.....)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a multiple selector by joining the indexes of your array:

```
$('#' + array.join(', #')).find(.....)
```

This way you don't loop through anything, you let jQuery deal with the fact that you're doing something to multiple elements.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/y7UQ9/

Docs for multiple selectors: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You've got a syntax error to start with:

```
$("#" + array[i]).find(.....)
```